# Cannot create a global git alias for pretty graphs

Tags: git

I m trying to create an alias using

git config --global alias.lg  log --all --decorate --oneline --graph

but this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
git config --global alias.lg "log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative"
```

this will:
-one commit per line

-show graph of commits

-abbreviated commit IDs

-dates relative to now

-show commit references (like git log --decorate)

-lots of colour

-show author of the commit

and for pretty git branches:

```
git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --all
```

i suggest you read it:
https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log
https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Use_graphviz_for_display
and read about git aliases:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotation marks around the option value, so it looks like this:

```
git config --global alias.lg "log --all --decorate --oneline --graph"
```

`git config`, when used to write an option, takes two positional arguments: the option name and the value.  Since your value is composed of multiple shell words, you need to quote it.